# Taylor's expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was brushing up on my calculus, when I came upon this question.

For the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = \cos{(x)}\exp{(x + y)}$
write down the Taylor expansion about $(0,0)$ up to second order.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\cos(t)$ and $\exp(t)$?  That would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
You can either apply *Taylor's formula* for two variables up to order $2$:
$$f'x,y)=f(0,0)+\bigl(f'_x(0,0)x+f'_y(0,0)\bigr)+\frac1{2!}\Bigl(f''_{x^2}(0,0)x^2+2f''_{xy}(0,0)xy+f''_{y^2}(0,0)y^2\Bigr)+o\bigl(\Vert(x,y)\Vert^2\bigr),$$
 or make the *Cauchy product* of the one-variable expansions of $\cos x$, $\mathrm e^x$ and $\mathrm e^y$, up to order $2$.